# Returning foreach() function is undefined than the value itself

Tags: javascript

I have tried foreach function , 
it is returning undefined rather than the value itself. i have no clue where did i go wrong .

```
 let value = Array.from(container).forEach((data) => {
        if(data.innerText === titleID){
          // -- when i console log this, it is returning the value i want 
          console.log(data.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName(kpiID)[0].innerText)
          // -- here it is returning underfine
          return data.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName(kpiID)[0].innerText;
          }
      });

value();
```

Based on my research,
Some say that we couldnt return value using foreach, some said its better to use filters. i am confuse which approach should i take. any advice? Thanks

Comment: Use map instead forEach.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `forEach` does not return anything. It just iterates on the array.

Maybe you need a combination of `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.filter`?

```js
let value = Array.from(container).map((data) => {
  if (data.innerText === titleID) {  console.log(data.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName(kpiID)[0].innerText)
    return data.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName(kpiID)[0].innerText;
  }
  return false;
}).filter(el => el !== false);
```

Because the map will have some falsy values for the elements which doesnt suffice the if-condition. So, you need `.filter` to remove those elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value from `forEach` to be the element in a new array, what you're looking for is `.map`

```
let value = Array.from(container).map(function(data){...});
```

Whatever you return in .map will be the matching element in the new array `value`

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `async` function where a Promise `resovle` the value instead of a return inside the forEach. Then `await` the value of the function.

This is one solution to get the result from the forEach.